# $T(n)=T(n-1)+O(\log n)$ is $T(n)=O(n^2)$ or $T(n)=O(n \log n)$

Tags: proof-verification, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

I have this Recurrence relation: $T(n)=T(n-1)+O(\log n)$

What is the solution?  $T(n)=O(n^2)$ or $T(n)=O(n \log n)$

What I did is:  I assume that $T(n)\le O(n^2)$
[image]

And that's bring me to $O(n^2)$, I'm right?
Or I have mistake?

Thank you!

Comment: Since $O(n\log n) \subseteq O(n^2)$, you are vacuously correct. :)  (But I'm not really being helpful.)

Comment: @anorton I disagree that you're not being helpful - because the correct answer here _is_ 'both', and knowing the difference between $O()$ and $\Theta()$ is important.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, So I was right? this is $O$ or $\Theta$? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is easier to do by repeated substitution. Your answer is technically correct, but often times big-oh notation is used rather than big-theta notation and I assume that your task was to show a tight asymptotic bound i.e. big-theta.

$T(n)=T(n-1)+\Theta(\log(n))$ implies

$T(n)=T(n-2)+\Theta(\log(n-1))+\Theta(\log(n))$, repeating this we get:

$T(n)=T(0)+\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}\Theta(\log(n-i))=T(0)+\Theta(\log(n!))=\Theta(n\log(n))$ by Stirling's approximation.

Comment: You don't need Stirling's approximation for this - just show that $T(n) \leq n\log n$ (trivial) and that $T(n)\geq cn\log n$ for some $c$ (almost trivial: look at the terms from $\frac n2$ to $n$).

Comment: I was referring to what some call Stirling's approximation in the computer science setting, that $\log(n!)\sim n\log(n)$.

Comment: Thank you! @NickC! But I need to show it for $O$ and not $\Theta$...:-)

Comment: It all is the same by changing the thetas to big-ohs. I put in thetas to clarify what the initial comments were referring to, about how you were technically correct but that is not what was meant by the exercise. If $f(n)=\Theta(g(n))$, then $f(n)=O(g(n))$.

Comment: So, I'm right, yes? It's $O$ or $\Theta$ of $n^2$, right?

Comment: $T(n)=O(n\log(n))$ is what the correct answer is. When one states the asymptotic bound, they normally show the "closest" function to the one being examined. $n\log(n)\leq n^2$ for all natural n, so we say $O(n\log(n))$ rather than $O(n^2)$.

Comment: But what I did is right?

Comment: No, the answer that is $O(n\log(n))$, and you only showed it was $O(n^2)$. As an example, say we have a function $f(n)=n$, then if the question is: is this function $O(n)$ or $O(n^10)$? Well the answer is $O(n)$, because it is a tighter bound than $O(n^10)$.

Comment: Nick, I disagree.  If the question is 'is this function $O(n)$ or $O(n^{10})$?', the correct answer is 'both'.  A function that is $O(n)$ is _also_ $O(n^{10})$, and if a question expects you to answer either-or then it's the question that's wrong.

Comment: I meant the "answer" in the sense of not just being true, but what was the original intention by either a textbook or an instructor. I do not think Yoar would get full credit for his answer, in short.